# Paste at mousepressEvent

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

I want to implement paste operation in Qt. I have implemented past operation but want to paste the items at the current position of mouse. Please suggest me the way to proceed. My code to above is as follows:
cadgraphicsscene.cpp

```
void CadGraphicsScene::cut()
{
    foreach (QGraphicsItem *item, itemList)
    {
        if (item->isSelected())
        {
            selectItems();
            removeItem(item);
            update();
        }
    }
}

void CadGraphicsScene::paste()
{
    selectItems();
    foreach (QGraphicsItem *item, itemList)
    {
        addItem(item);
    }
}

void CadGraphicsScene::selectItems()
{
    // refresh record of selected items and their starting positions
    selectedItems.clear();
    foreach (QGraphicsItem *item, itemList)
    {
        if (item->isSelected())
        {
            if (dynamic_cast<QGraphicsItem *>(item))
            {
                selectedItems.append(qMakePair(
                                         dynamic_cast<QGraphicsItem *>(item),
                                         item->scenePos()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```